# VS 2010 gives error LNK2001 when using Runtime Library option Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamic-linking

I have a solution with 9 projects. The projects are using Boost 1.49, which I have already build for VS2010 for both release and debug mode using both shared and static runtime-link option. In Release mode, when I am compiling all the projects with Runtime Library option set to **Multi-threaded (/MT)**, it compiles fine. But when I use Runtime Library option set to **Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)**, I got a lot of linking errors.

FYI, among the 9 projects,  8 project's 'Configuration Type' are set to **Static Library (.lib)** and some of these 8 projects depends on other projects among them. When I build these 8 projects independently using Runtime Library option set to **Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)**, they compile fine.

But when I try to compile the only other project, with **/MD** option I got linking errors. This project's 'Configuration Type' is set to **Dynamic Library (.dll)**. And this project is using all the 8 other projects .lib files to create it's .dll file.

For convenience I am providing my build output that shows the errors [truncated for character limit]:

```
8>BaseMulti.lib(src10.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src11.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src12.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src13.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src14.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_49.lib(thread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>StringPrep.lib(src15.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src16.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src17.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src18.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src19.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src20.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src21.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src22.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src23.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src24.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src25.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src26.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src27.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src28.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src29.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src30.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src31.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src33.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src34.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src35.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src36.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src37.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src38.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src39.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src40.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src41.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src42.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src43.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src44.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src45.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src46.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src47.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>src48.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>BaseMulti.lib(TextUtil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>BaseMulti.lib(tstring.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src49.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src4.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src5.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src1.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>asyncRes.lib(ares_process1.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src8.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src2.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src3.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src11.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src12.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src6.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src7.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_49.lib(thread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>StringPrep.lib(src15.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>BaseMulti.lib(Base64.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>BaseMulti.lib(src10.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src17.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src18.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src13.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src14.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src21.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src22.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src23.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src16.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src25.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src26.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src27.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src20.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src29.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src30.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src31.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src24.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src33.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src34.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src35.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src28.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src36.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src37.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src38.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src40.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src41.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src42.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src43.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src44.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src45.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src46.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src47.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>src48.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>BaseMulti.lib(TextUtil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>BaseMulti.lib(tstring.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>PAL.lib(src49.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z)
8>BaseMulti.lib(TextUtil.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__toupper
8>BaseMulti.lib(tstring.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (__imp_?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::flush(void)" (__imp_?flush@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV12@XZ)
8>BaseMulti.lib(tstring.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (__imp_?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Osfx(void)" (__imp_?_Osfx@?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXXZ)
8>BaseMulti.lib(tstring.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::uncaught_exception(void)" (__imp_?uncaught_exception@std@@YA_NXZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) bool __cdecl std::uncaught_exception(void)" (__imp_?uncaught_exception@std@@YA_NXZ)
8>BaseMulti.lib(tstring.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (__imp_?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setstate(int,bool)" (__imp_?setstate@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z)
8>BaseMulti.lib(tstring.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (__imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputn(char const *,__int64)" (__imp_?sputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE_JPBD_J@Z)
8>BaseMulti.lib(tstring.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char)" (__imp_?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHD@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sputc(char)" (__imp_?sputc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEHD@Z)
8>yyyyy.lib(src20.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__puts
8>libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_49.lib(thread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___beginthreadex
8>PAL.lib(PALthread.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___beginthreadex
8>StringPrep.lib(StringPrepWithSaslPrepProfile.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base0::_Orphan_all(void)" (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base0@std@@QAEXXZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Lock(void)" (?_Lock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAEXXZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Unlock(void)" (?_Unlock@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAEXXZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::showmanyc(void)" (?showmanyc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAE_JXZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::uflow(void)" (?uflow@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAEHXZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::xsgetn(char *,__int64)" (?xsgetn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAE_JPAD_J@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual __int64 __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::xsputn(char const *,__int64)" (?xsputn@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAE_JPBD_J@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::setbuf(char *,__int64)" (?setbuf@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAEPAV12@PAD_J@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual int __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::sync(void)" (?sync@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAEHXZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::imbue(class std::locale const &)" (?imbue@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@MAEXABVlocale@2@@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) __int64 const std::_BADOFF" (__imp_?_BADOFF@std@@3_JB)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: char * __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::_Pninc(void)" (__imp_?_Pninc@?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAEPADXZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) protected: __thiscall std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (__imp_??0?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@IAE@XZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) private: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Ios_base_dtor(class std::ios_base *)" (__imp_?_Ios_base_dtor@ios_base@std@@CAXPAV12@@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) const std::ios_base::`vftable'" (__imp_??_7ios_base@std@@6B@)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) const std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::`vftable'" (__imp_??_7?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@6B@)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@UAE@XZ)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::basic_iostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >(class std::basic_streambuf<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > *)" (__imp_??0?$basic_iostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAE@PAV?$basic_streambuf@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned int)" (__imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@I@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::operator<<(unsigned short)" (__imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@G@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src9.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::basic_ios<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >::clear(int,bool)" (__imp_?clear@?$basic_ios@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEXH_N@Z)
8>Netmulti.lib(src4.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__vsnprintf
8>Netmulti.lib(src50.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__vsnprintf
8>Netmulti.lib(src4.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___snprintf
8>Netmulti.lib(src4.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__rewind
8>asyncRes.lib(ares_init1.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___wcsdup
8>asyncRes.lib(ares_init1.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp___getpid
8>../Bin/ReleaseU/somelib.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 41 unresolved externals
9>------ Rebuild All started: Project: yyyyyCInterfaceToDll, Configuration: Unicode Release Static Win32 ------
9>  yyyyy.cpp
9>yyyyy.cpp(47): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
9>yyyyy.cpp(403): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
9>yyyyy.cpp(483): warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
9>  yyyyyCInterfaceToDll.vcxproj -> E:\somepath\src\yyyyyCInterfaceToDll\Unicode Release Static\yyyyyCInterfaceToDll.lib
========== Rebuild All: 8 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Don't know where I am missing the trick. Please let me come out from the black hole.

Best Regards

Khaled